# Convert DataRow to Object with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper, datarow

I can successfully map from IDataReader to a List of objects but when I want to take one DataRow it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Am I missing something simple here?

```
[TestFixture]
public class AutomapperTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("contact");
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
        dt.Columns.Add("Line1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Line2");
        dt.Columns.Add("Line3");
        dt.Columns.Add("Suburb");
        dt.Columns.Add("State");
        dt.Columns.Add("Postcode");

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row.ItemArray = new [] { "Little", "Johnny", 
                                 "1 Random Place", "", "", 
                                 "Windsor", "Qld", "4030" };

        var dest = Mapper.DynamicMap<myObject>(row);

        Assert.AreEqual(row["FirstName"], "Little");
        Assert.IsNotNull(dest);
        Assert.AreEqual(dest.FirstName, "Little");
    }
}
```

Destination type:

```
public class myObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to implement your own custom value resolver

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers

**UPDATE**

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver
{
    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        return source.New( Convert.ChangeType((source.Context.SourceValue as DataRow)[source.Context.MemberName], source.Context.DestinationType));
    }
}
```

and here is how to use it

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DataRow,myObject>().ForAllMembers(m=>m.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
var dest = Mapper.Map<myObject>(row);
```

I recommend using Dapper. That way your data coming from database will be strongly typed or dynamic, and Automapper should be able to figure out the mappings.

CSV files can be read by Dapper through ODBC, I believe. But for CSV I'd recommend the LinqToCSV Nuget package instead.

Comment: Thanks - that's unfortunate, it hardly seems worth it for a small number of columns.

Comment: Consider Dapper with Automapper.

Comment: Can you give an example how custom value resolver can help here?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Is the sample OK?

Comment: I've learned something too @Geoff. It was my first true encounter with Automapper and custom value resolvers.

Comment: Trying to get this to work for version 5.0.2 with the changed interface, maintainer says "AutoMapper doesn't support this scenario."

Comment: Could you post a new case and link?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the ITypeConverter:

Create a custom TypeConverter class:

```
public class DataRowConverter : ITypeConverter<DataRow, Object>
{
    Object ITypeConverter<DataRow, Object>.Convert(DataRow source, Object destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in source.Table.Columns)
        {
            var value = source[col].ToString();

            PropertyInfo prop = destination.GetType().GetProperty(
                col.ColumnName,
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);

            if (prop != null && prop.CanWrite)
            {
                prop.SetValue(destination, value, null);
            }
        }

        return destination;
    }
}
```

Then set the config:

```
cfg.CreateMap<DataRow, Object>().ConvertUsing<DataRowConverter>();
```

Finally, use the mapper as usual:

```
var results = new List<SearchResult>();
foreach (DataRow row in Res.data.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var obj = mapper.Map<SearchResult>(row);
    results.Add(obj);
}
```

It should work with the latest version of AutoMapper.