# How to map DataTable to DTO by using automapper

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, automapper

I'm new to AutoMapper and have couple of questions regarding datatable to object mapping. I have sqlquery code and sql result. I want to do object to object  map with automapper. any help's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it could go something like this (broad lines):

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<DataSet, CompanyModel>()
     .ForMember(m => m.Company, opt => opt.MapFrom(r => r.Tables[0].Columns["Company"]))
     .ForMember(m => m.Customers, opt => opt.MapFrom(r => r.Tables[0].Columns["Customers"]))
     .ForMember(m => m.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom(r => Double.Parse(r.Tables[0].Columns["Amount"]));
```

and then

```
Mapper.Map<List<CompanyModel>>(ds);
```

Providing more details (code) would probably result in more precise answers.

Comment: I tried your code but Not WorkingError:An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code.

Answer (score 2):

Look here [Convert DataRow to Object with AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665660/convert-datarow-to-object-with-automapper)

For now I did this based on above, so far I have only tested with flat DTO with Primitive types:

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver
{
    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        return source.New(Convert.ChangeType((source.Context.SourceValue as DataRow)[source.Context.MemberName], source.Context.DestinationType));
    }
}


public static class DtoTransformDataTable<T> where T : new()
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> JustDoIt(DataTable dt)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<DataRow, T>().ForAllMembers(m => m.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
        var listOfT = new List<T>();

        foreach (var item in dt.Rows) //Use LINQ to concise
        {
            var dest = Mapper.Map<T>(item);
            listOfT.Add(dest);
        }
        return listOfT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't think that works with AutoMapper 5 - the IValueResolver interface has changed - https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported by Automapper out of the box if you are using plain untyped `DataTables`/`DataSets`.

However, if you create a typed `DataTable`/`DataSet` then things should work better. A typed `DataSet` gives your table rows properties for each column and should be easier to use with AutoMapper.

I haven't used typed `DataSets` in years, but they are still supported in .Net. [Look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb.aspx) for some information on how to set them up.