# Auto Mapper - DataTable to Generic type (for DTO) mapping not working

Tags: c#, datatable, automapper

I am trying to transform a DataTable retrieved using Ado.Net into a DTO. The DTO of type "T" being passed has exactly the same field and same datatype as the DataTable but I get the exception below:

Is this doable?
Brady Holt at geekytidbits has an old article to do the following but DynamicMap is obsolete now!

List people = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap>(
sourceDataTable.CreateDataReader());

---

Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type

IDataReader -> UserDto (Destination member list)
System.Data.IDataReader -> MyApp.Console.UserDto (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
UserId // int type
FirstName // string type
LastName // string type

---

**Code below:**

```
public static class DtoTransformDataTable<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> JustDoIt(DataTable dt)
    {
              var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, IEnumerable<T>>();
        });

              var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

              try
              {
                  mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  throw ex;
              }

              var listOfT = mapper.Map<List<T>>(dt.CreateDataReader());

        return listOfT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then don't use AutoMapper. Use LINQ to select a collection of items individually.

Comment: I will prefer not having to code separately for each DTO which may have different fields. However each DTO will correspond to DataTable being retrieved by Stored Procedure.

Comment: Can you use Entity Framework? That supports executing a Stored Procedure and automatically translating it into a C# object. I'm fairly certain you'd have to create AutoMapper settings for each DTO you are using.

Comment: Im with krillgar, AutoMapper can seem like a magic bullet,  I was an advovate but then I realised amongst others, it was taking more than it was giving back. Free yourself while you can.

Comment: Thanks guys found solution from another SO post.

Answer (score 0):

On another post someone says that the IDataReader support has been removed from Automapper 4.0 up.

But I found answer at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665660/convert-datarow-to-object-with-automapper)