# How to use AutoMapper without Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am learning how to use AutoMapper. First thing first, I don't use Entity Framework to read my data.

Hence, in my case I have to do manual mapping for each of the properties of my response model.

Below code may help you get more insight of this:

Response model:

```
 public class TotalLossResults
 {
     public string N_CLAIM_NUMBER { get; set; }
     public string N_CLAIM_ID { get; set; }             
 }
```

MapperClass:

```
 public class TLResultsMapper : Profile
 {
     private TotalLossResults tlResultsObj = new TotalLossResults();

     public TLResultsMapper()
     {
         IMappingExpression<DataRow, TotalLossResults> mappingExpression = CreateMap<DataRow, TotalLossResults>();

         foreach (var prop in tlResultsObj.GetType().GetProperties())
         {
             mappingExpression.ForMember(prop.Name, y => y.MapFrom(s => s[prop.Name]));
         }
     }
 }
```

Note: in the mapper class I used for each to get rid of the `mappingExpression.ForMember` statement for each property. But this works only when the property name is the same as of the column name (entity name for example) of the result which I get from the database.

I am looking out for some option where I can take similar approach to map the data values to my response model properties when the property's names are not matching with the column names.

I tried doing something like this:

I created another class which has the properties with different names:

```
public class TLResultsDifferentNames
{
    public string N_CLAIM_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string N_CLAIM_ID { get; set; }
}
```

and a mapper implementation like this:

```
private TLResultsDifferentNames tlResultsObj = new TLResultsDifferentNames ();
private TotalLossResults tlResultsColObj = new TotalLossResults ();*

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i<tlResultsObj.GetType().GetProperties().Length - 1 && j<tlResultsColObj.GetType().GetProperties().Length - 1; i++, j++)
{
    mappingExpression.ForMember(tlResultsObj.GetType().GetProperties()[i].Name, y => y.MapFrom(s => s[tlResultsColObj.GetType().GetProperties()[j].Name]));
}
```

But this doesn't work. It binds the last column values to all the model properties.

Any help/suggestion to achieve the mapping without using the manual way of mapping would be very helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert DataRow to Object with AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665660/convert-datarow-to-object-with-automapper)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this dint solve my problem; however, i have found something interesting and i will be posting the solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I could find something really interesting in Auto Mapper today. Which is Attribute Mapping and using that i need not to worry about any sort of manual/dynamical mapping for my models.

Below is the code which works perfectly now for all the properties:

Ex1: here all the properties' names are same

```
 [AutoMap(typeof(object))] //this takes our Source class name
    public class TotalLossResults
     {
         public string N_CLAIM_NUMBER { get; set; }
         public string N_CLAIM_ID { get; set; }             
     }
```

Ex2: here we got different properties

```
 [AutoMap(typeof(TotalLossResults))] //this takes our Source class name
 public class TLResultsDifferentNames
{
    [SourceMember(nameof(TotalLossResults.N_CLAIM_NUMBER))]
    public string claimNumberOfJack { get; set; }
    public string claimIDofJack { get; set; }
}
```

For mapping configuration we gonna use the below code:

```
var config1 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
cfg.AddMaps(typeof(TotalLossResults))); 
var mapper = new Mapper(config1);     

var response = mapper.Map<TotalLossResults>(sourceObject);
```

Note: Its better to have the configs created in App Start.